# How to move marker along polyline using google map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to move the marker according to the polyline and with animation. Similar to the below image:

[image: Taken from Mapbox]

[Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/) is already giving this kind of demo. But I want to achieve the same using Google maps. However right now my marker is not rotating along the path.
Here is what I have tried:

```
private void onReady(List<LatLng> polyz) {

      for (int i = 0; i < polyz.size() - 1; i++) {
        LatLng src = polyz.get(i);
        LatLng dest = polyz.get(i + 1);
        Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
            .add(new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude),
                new LatLng(dest.latitude, dest.longitude))
            .width(2).color(Color.RED).geodesic(true));

      }
      LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
      builder.include(polyz.get(0));
      builder.include(polyz.get(polyz.size()-1));
      map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 48));
      map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(7), 1000, null);
      BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car);
      marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
          .position(polyz.get(0))
          .title("Curr")
          .snippet("Move"));
      marker.setIcon(icon);

    }
```

And the animation:

```
    private void animateMarker(GoogleMap myMap, final Marker marker, final List<LatLng> directionPoint,
      final boolean hideMarker) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    Projection proj = myMap.getProjection();
    final long duration = 600000;

    final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
      int i = 0;

      @Override
      public void run() {
        long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
        float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed
            / duration);
        Location location=new Location(String.valueOf(directionPoint.get(i)));
        Location newlocation=new Location(String.valueOf(directionPoint.get(i+1)));
        marker.setAnchor(0.5f, 0.5f);
        marker.setRotation(location.bearingTo(newlocation)  - 45);
        if (i < directionPoint.size()) {
          marker.setPosition(directionPoint.get(i));
        }
        i++;

        if (t < 1.0) {
          // Post again 16ms later.
          handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
        } else {
          if (hideMarker) {
            marker.setVisible(false);
          } else {
            marker.setVisible(true);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: have you solved this

Answer (score 31):

You can use for your task your approach based on custom marker animation: animate separately car movement and car turns throughout all direction points. For this You need 2 kinds of animation:

1) animation for car movement;

2) animation for car turn;

which calls each other on its end (car movement animation on end calls car turn animation and vice versa: car turn animation on its end calls car movement animation and so for all points of car path).

For example on fig.:

[image]

1) animation for car movement from `P0` to `P1`;

2) animation for car turn on `P1`;

3) animation for car movement from `P1` to `P2`

and so on.

Car movement animation can be implemented by method like this:

```
private void animateCarMove(final Marker marker, final LatLng beginLatLng, final LatLng endLatLng, final long duration) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final long startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

        final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

        // set car bearing for current part of path
        float angleDeg = (float)(180 * getAngle(beginLatLng, endLatLng) / Math.PI);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(angleDeg);
        marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(mMarkerIcon, 0, 0, mMarkerIcon.getWidth(), mMarkerIcon.getHeight(), matrix, true)));

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // calculate phase of animation
                long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
                float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed / duration);
                // calculate new position for marker
                double lat = (endLatLng.latitude - beginLatLng.latitude) * t + beginLatLng.latitude;
                double lngDelta = endLatLng.longitude - beginLatLng.longitude;

                if (Math.abs(lngDelta) > 180) {
                    lngDelta -= Math.signum(lngDelta) * 360;
                }
                double lng = lngDelta * t + beginLatLng.longitude;

                marker.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lng));

                // if not end of line segment of path 
                if (t < 1.0) {
                    // call next marker position
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
                } else {
                    // call turn animation
                    nextTurnAnimation();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

where

`mMarkerIcon` is:

```
Bitmap mMarkerIcon;
...
mMarkerIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.the_car);  // for your car icon in file the_car.png in drawable folder
```

and car icon should be North oriented:

[image]

for correct rotation apply

`nextTurnAnimation()` - method called on end of car movement animation to start car turn animation:

```
private void nextTurnAnimation() {
        mIndexCurrentPoint++;

        if (mIndexCurrentPoint < mPathPolygonPoints.size() - 1) {
            LatLng prevLatLng = mPathPolygonPoints.get(mIndexCurrentPoint - 1);
            LatLng currLatLng = mPathPolygonPoints.get(mIndexCurrentPoint);
            LatLng nextLatLng = mPathPolygonPoints.get(mIndexCurrentPoint + 1);

            float beginAngle = (float)(180 * getAngle(prevLatLng, currLatLng) / Math.PI);
            float endAngle = (float)(180 * getAngle(currLatLng, nextLatLng) / Math.PI);

            animateCarTurn(mCarMarker, beginAngle, endAngle, TURN_ANIMATION_DURATION);
        }
    }
```

In its turn car turn animation method can be like this:

```
private void animateCarTurn(final Marker marker, final float startAngle, final float endAngle, final long duration) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final long startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

        final float dAndgle = endAngle - startAngle;

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(startAngle);
        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mMarkerIcon, 0, 0, mMarkerIcon.getWidth(), mMarkerIcon.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(rotatedBitmap));

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
                float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed / duration);

                Matrix m = new Matrix();
                m.postRotate(startAngle + dAndgle * t);
                marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(mMarkerIcon, 0, 0, mMarkerIcon.getWidth(), mMarkerIcon.getHeight(), m, true)));

                if (t < 1.0) {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
                } else {
                    nextMoveAnimation();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

where `nextMoveAnimation()` is:

```
private void nextMoveAnimation() {
        if (mIndexCurrentPoint <  mPathPolygonPoints.size() - 1) {
            animateCarMove(mCarMarker, mPathPolygonPoints.get(mIndexCurrentPoint), mPathPolygonPoints.get(mIndexCurrentPoint+1), MOVE_ANIMATION_DURATION);
        }
    }
```

The `mPathPolygonPoints` (geopoints of car trip) is:

```
private List<LatLng> mPathPolygonPoints;
```

And the `mIndexCurrentPoint` variable is index of current point on path (it should be 0 at start of animation and incremented on each turn of path in `nextTurnAnimation()` method).

`TURN_ANIMATION_DURATION` - duration (in ms) animation for car turn on path geopoint;

`MOVE_ANIMATION_DURATION` - duration (in ms) animation for car movement along line segment of path;

To get bearing You can use method like that:

```
private double getAngle(LatLng beginLatLng, LatLng endLatLng) {
        double f1 = Math.PI * beginLatLng.latitude / 180;
        double f2 = Math.PI * endLatLng.latitude / 180;
        double dl = Math.PI * (endLatLng.longitude - beginLatLng.longitude) / 180;
        return Math.atan2(Math.sin(dl) * Math.cos(f2) , Math.cos(f1) * Math.sin(f2) - Math.sin(f1) * Math.cos(f2) * Math.cos(dl));;
    }
```

Finally You can start all animations by call `animateCarMove()` once:

```
animateCarMove(mCarMarker, mPathPolygonPoints.get(0), mPathPolygonPoints.get(1), MOVE_ANIMATION_DURATION);
```

other steps of animation will be called automatically for each point of car path.

And You should take into account some "special cases" like:

1) changing sign of of turn angle (e.g. bearing changes from -120 to 150 degrees);

2) possibilities for interrupt of animation by user;

3) calculate animation duration on path segment length (e.g. 1 sec for 1 km of segment length instead of fixed `MOVE_ANIMATION_DURATION`)

4) probably tune value `16` in `handler.postDelayed(this, 16);` line for better performance;

5) and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.Can you tell me how should I handle this **special case** changing sign of of turn angle (e.g. bearing changes from -120 to 150 degrees).

Comment: As you said when I am getting the angle -122 to 171 degree the marker rotates more than it is needed. How to handle this kind of situation.

Comment: You should detect clockwise and clockwise turns and if sign is changed animate "+" or "-" (360 - |angle|) turn.

Comment: What do you mean by angle.Is it startAngle or endAngle. And what I am able to understand is that if it changes from 120 to -150 then it would be like this (360-(-150)) i.e (360+150).

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me a lot :)

Comment: Thanks @AndriyOmelchenko.. :)

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko thank you this works great . can you edit the answer to cover this point please ? 1) changing sign of of turn angle (e.g. bearing changes from -120 to 150 degrees);

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko could you please tell me how to set geo points to mPathPolygonPoints ,  I mean I can put previous and current location but how to set future location as you are getting future points by
 mPathPolygonPoints.get(mIndexCurrentPoint + 1);  . As user can go in backwards direction .

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko i was use your code to move marker but it now move exact on path

Comment: @VishalThakkar Use [anchor](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions#anchor(float,%20float)) method to adjust marker position.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko i  was set marker but its  show like this https://imgur.com/a/gvZ4f

Comment: @VishalThakkar Add `marker.setAnchor(0.5f, 0.5f);` (or something like that) after `marker.setIcon(..)` line. Then, may be, adjust `0.5f, 0.5f` parameters to other, if needed.

Comment: cam anyone explains these mPathPolygonPoints list , how do i get these list  geopoints

Comment: @SumitKumar It depends on your task: from Firebase database, server side, cloud, local database or local file, etc. Its vehicle path points.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko thanks i am getting lat long one by one when driver moves , so i have to add that lat long in this list mPathPolygonPoints ? correct ?

Comment: @SumitKumar Yes.

Comment: This is copied from google sample code, go there and use that instead of this. https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the way you are creating your `Location` objects. You are using the `Location (String provider)` constructor that *Construct a new Location with a named provider* [(documentation)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#Location(java.lang.String)):

> By default time, latitude and longitude are 0, and the location has no bearing, altitude, speed, accuracy or extras.

In your case you are not creating a `Location` with your desired coordinates but a `Location` whose provider's name is `String.valueOf(directionPoint.get(i))` but the `Location` objects are created with latitude and longitude = 0.

The correct way to create the `Location` objects is as follows:

```
Location location = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
location.setLatitude(directionPoint.get(i).latitude);
location.setLongitude(directionPoint.get(i).longitude);

Location newlocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
newlocation.setLatitude(directionPoint.get(i+1).latitude);
newlocation.setLongitude(directionPoint.get(i+1).longitude);
```

Anyway take into account that you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because you are not taking into account that `i+1` will be `==directionPoint.size()` in the end.

Comment: Thanks fro your answer.I have tried  `SphericalUtil.computeHeading(beginLatLng,endLatLng)` for the bearing calculation. The marker rotates but not smoothly that where it is paining.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is [Marker Animations](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations).

> You can animate markers so that they exhibit dynamic movement in a
>   variety of different circumstances. To specify the way a marker is
>   animated, use the marker's animation property, of type
>   google.maps.Animation. The following Animation values are supported:
>
> -DROP indicates that the marker should drop from the top of the map to its final location when first placed on the map. Animation will cease
>   once the marker comes to rest and animation will revert to null. This
>   type of animation is usually specified during creation of the Marker.
>
> -BOUNCE indicates that the marker should bounce in place. A bouncing marker will continue bouncing until its animation property is
>   explicitly set to null.

Here's a snippet from the guide:

```
var marker;

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 13,
          center: {lat: 59.325, lng: 18.070}
        });

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          draggable: true,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          position: {lat: 59.327, lng: 18.067}
        });
        marker.addListener('click', toggleBounce);
      }

      function toggleBounce() {
        if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
          marker.setAnimation(null);
        } else {
          marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer .But I am working not native android app,can you provide the example in java.