# Marker moving through polyline in Mapbox

Tags: android, mapbox, polyline, mapbox-marker

I'm facing a real challenge which I hope you guys can help me figure out.
I'm creating a polyline for given Position objects, and what I'd want to do, is to put a custom marker in the origin and make it move all through the polyline, not necessarily tracking a position, just moving over the polyline.

My first step was creating an ObjectAnimation object, and make it move in a line from one marker to another, but i'm not figuring out how can I make it move along my polyline and not in a line.

Thank you in advance, and any further information you guys need to clarify the issue, i'm viewing this topic at every time!

Comment: Try if this post can help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40526350/how-to-move-marker-along-polyline-using-google-map/40686476)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have an [example for this](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/labs/MarkerFollowingRouteActivity.java)

you're correct in using an object animator, you also need to make use of a handler to keep updating the position.

```
// Animating the marker requires the use of both the ValueAnimator and a handler.
    // The ValueAnimator is used to move the marker between the GeoJSON points, this is
    // done linearly. The handler is used to move the marker along the GeoJSON points.
    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {

        // Check if we are at the end of the points list, if so we want to stop using
        // the handler.
        if ((points.size() - 1) > count) {

          // Calculating the distance is done between the current point and next.
          // This gives us the duration we will need to execute the ValueAnimator.
          // Multiplying by ten is done to slow down the marker speed. Adjusting
          // this value will result in the marker traversing faster or slower along
          // the line
          distance = (long) marker.getPosition().distanceTo(points.get(count)) * 10;

          // animate the marker from it's current position to the next point in the
          // points list.
          ValueAnimator markerAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(marker, "position",
              new LatLngEvaluator(), marker.getPosition(), points.get(count));
          markerAnimator.setDuration(distance);
          markerAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
          markerAnimator.start();

          // This line will make sure the marker appears when it is being animated
          // and starts outside the current user view. Without this, the user must
          // intentionally execute a gesture before the view marker reappears on
          // the map.
          map.getMarkerViewManager().update();

          // Keeping the current point count we are on.
          count++;

          // Once we finish we need to repeat the entire process by executing the
          // handler again once the ValueAnimator is finished.
          handler.postDelayed(this, distance);
        }
      }
    };
    handler.post(runnable);
```