# Animate marker on Polyline path

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I have `3 markers` on a Google Map.

1. *`Two Markers`* to show `starting and ending points`

Here is the code using *to draw a Polyline* between these two points:

```
private void polyLine() {

    LatLng starting = new LatLng(##.######, ##.######);
    LatLng ending = new LatLng(##.######, ##.######);

    PolylineOptions line = new PolylineOptions().add(starting, ending);

    mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(starting).title("Start"));
    mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ending).title("End"));

    mGoogleMap.addPolyline(line);

}
```

2. *`One Marker`* to show `current Location` [HUE_ROSE]

And to *`animate marker to current location`* using:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Location Changed " + location.getLatitude()
            + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    mLastLocation = location;

    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    if(ourGlobalMarker == null) { // First time adding marker to map
        ourGlobalMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE)));
        MarkerAnimation.animateMarkerToICS(ourGlobalMarker, latLng, new LatLngInterpolator.Spherical());
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 18));
    } else {
        MarkerAnimation.animateMarkerToICS(ourGlobalMarker, latLng, new LatLngInterpolator.Spherical());
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 18));
    }

}
```

**PROBLEM:**

*`Getting Animating Marker, but right side of Polyline`*

**SOLUTION:**

*`How Can I show Animated Marker on Polyline Path`*

I *tried a lot* to find *`solution`* for this one, but `did not find` any thing, share your `suggestions`.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40526350/6950238) question and answers.

Comment: can your share the screenshot and demo project

Comment: @PhanVanLinh see this is what I wanted to get at the end: stackoverflow.com/questions/46103680/map-and-moving-marker-using-google-maps-api     If you can help me in getting this, it means you answered both the questions :) I already shared updated code of mine in both the SO questions...

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you have 3 marker
1. Source point
2. Destination Point
3. Moving marker

you have to try this way it will help you

```
private void animateMarkerNew(final LatLng startPosition, final LatLng destination, final Marker marker) {

        if (marker != null) {

            final LatLng endPosition = new LatLng(destination.latitude, destination.longitude);

            final float startRotation = marker.getRotation();
            final LatLngInterpolatorNew latLngInterpolator = new LatLngInterpolatorNew.LinearFixed();

            ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
            valueAnimator.setDuration(2000); // duration 3 second
            valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    try {
                        float v = animation.getAnimatedFraction();
                        LatLng newPosition = latLngInterpolator.interpolate(v, startPosition, endPosition);
                        marker.setPosition(newPosition);
                        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                .target(newPosition)
                                .zoom(18f)
                                .build()));

                        marker.setRotation(getBearing(startPosition, new LatLng(destination.latitude, destination.longitude)));
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        //I don't care atm..
                    }
                }
            });
            valueAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);

                    // if (mMarker != null) {
                    // mMarker.remove();
                    // }
                    // mMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(endPosition).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon_car)));

                }
            });
            valueAnimator.start();
        }
    }
```

Note: marker is mean which marker you want to animate that one.

```
 private interface LatLngInterpolatorNew {
        LatLng interpolate(float fraction, LatLng a, LatLng b);

        class LinearFixed implements LatLngInterpolatorNew {
            @Override
            public LatLng interpolate(float fraction, LatLng a, LatLng b) {
                double lat = (b.latitude - a.latitude) * fraction + a.latitude;
                double lngDelta = b.longitude - a.longitude;
                // Take the shortest path across the 180th meridian.
                if (Math.abs(lngDelta) > 180) {
                    lngDelta -= Math.signum(lngDelta) * 360;
                }
                double lng = lngDelta * fraction + a.longitude;
                return new LatLng(lat, lng);
            }
        }
    }


//Method for finding bearing between two points
private float getBearing(LatLng begin, LatLng end) {
    double lat = Math.abs(begin.latitude - end.latitude);
    double lng = Math.abs(begin.longitude - end.longitude);

    if (begin.latitude < end.latitude && begin.longitude < end.longitude)
        return (float) (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat)));
    else if (begin.latitude >= end.latitude && begin.longitude < end.longitude)
        return (float) ((90 - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat))) + 90);
    else if (begin.latitude >= end.latitude && begin.longitude >= end.longitude)
        return (float) (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat)) + 180);
    else if (begin.latitude < end.latitude && begin.longitude >= end.longitude)
        return (float) ((90 - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat))) + 270);
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Time saver: `Take the shortest path across the 180th meridian`

Answer (score 1):

Try out with setting anchor like follows

```
mDetailPositionMarker = mDetailGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(newLatLonValue)
                    .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                    .rotation(bearingValue)
                    .flat(true)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.biketopicon)));
```

And make sure your icon will not be having any padding or margin. Avoid unnecessary space in icon image than the content like shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
    // Animation handler for old APIs without animation support
private void animateMarkerTo(final Marker marker, final double lat, final double lng) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    final long DURATION_MS = 3000;
    final Interpolator interpolator = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();
    final LatLng startPosition = marker.getPosition();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            float elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
            float t = elapsed/DURATION_MS;
            float v = interpolator.getInterpolation(t);

            double currentLat = (lat - startPosition.latitude) * v + startPosition.latitude;
            double currentLng = (lng - startPosition.longitude) * v + startPosition.longitude;
            marker.setPosition(new LatLng(currentLat, currentLng));

            // if animation is not finished yet, repeat
            if (t < 1) {
                handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

call this method inside onLocationChange method and pass location lat and lang then you will see a magic ;)