# Draw ARC Polyline in Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-custom-view, polyline

**How Can I Draw Arc Polyline in Google Map ?**

I already used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43665433) code to create **curved** Polyline.

Here is the **method** to draw curved Polyline:

```
private void showCurvedPolyline (LatLng p1, LatLng p2, double k) {
    //Calculate distance and heading between two points
    double d = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(p1,p2);
    double h = SphericalUtil.computeHeading(p1, p2);

    //Midpoint position
    LatLng p = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(p1, d*0.5, h);

    //Apply some mathematics to calculate position of the circle center
    double x = (1-k*k)*d*0.5/(2*k);
    double r = (1+k*k)*d*0.5/(2*k);

    LatLng c = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(p, x, h + 90.0);

    //Polyline options
    PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions();
    List<PatternItem> pattern = Arrays.<PatternItem>asList(new Dash(30), new Gap(20));

    //Calculate heading between circle center and two points
    double h1 = SphericalUtil.computeHeading(c, p1);
    double h2 = SphericalUtil.computeHeading(c, p2);

    //Calculate positions of points on circle border and add them to polyline options
    int numpoints = 100;
    double step = (h2 -h1) / numpoints;

    for (int i=0; i < numpoints; i++) {
        LatLng pi = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(c, r, h1 + i * step);
        options.add(pi);
    }

    //Draw polyline
    mMap.addPolyline(options.width(10).color(Color.MAGENTA).geodesic(false).pattern(pattern));
}
```

OUTPUT

## 1. If I am using this.showCurvedPolyline(latLng1, latLng2, 0.1); then getting:

[image]

As you can see in above image, we are very close to get our target, but don't know why it's not connecting with another end point

## 2. If I am using this.showCurvedPolyline(latLng1, latLng2, 1); then getting:

[image]

## 3. If I am using LatLng c = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(p, x, h - 90.0); then getting:

[image]

**Note:** I don't want this much *big circle shape*, really **I don't want** that much *height*.

Here is what **I want an ARC Shape** as shown in below image

[image]

Here is the **CODE** I am using to *add curved Polyline* between two `geo-locatios` :

```
private void addCurvedPolyLine() {

        LatLng latLng1 = new LatLng(40.7128, 74.0059); // New York
        LatLng latLng2 = new LatLng(51.5074, 0.1278); // London

        Marker marker1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng1).title("Start"));
        Marker marker2 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng2).title("End"));

        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

        builder.include(marker1.getPosition());
        builder.include(marker2.getPosition());

        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
        int padding = 0; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
        mMap.moveCamera(cu);
        mMap.animateCamera(cu);

        this.showCurvedPolyline(latLng1, latLng2, 0.1);

    }
```

Comment: He has provided a solution by using k=1 instead of k==1, see his second problem in quick fix [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46398634/8244632).

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar I didn't find k==1 anywhere in above method, can you tell me exactly where I need to make changes.

Comment: see this function call this.showCurvedPolyline(sydney1,sydney2, 0.5); 0.5 here is the value of k, try passing 1 here.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tell you I already tried with 1.0 and 1 but same problem: this.showCurvedPolyline(latLng2, latLng1, 1);

Comment: As they have mentioned "The last parameter k defines the curvature of the polyline, it can be >0 and <=1. In my example I used k=0.5", Have you tried changing that value to .2 or .3 which is less than the previous value. Also, changing 0.5 to 1 led to any change?

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar Please have a look above, I just updated few things.

Answer (score 8):

The solution that I proposed in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43305664/can-i-draw-a-curved-dashed-line-in-google-maps-android/43665433#43665433) was focused on curved polylines for really small distances. For example, when you have a Directions API route where the start and end points are snapped to road, but the real start and end points in original request were the positions of buildings, so you can connect the road and building with this curved dashed polyline.

In case of big distances like in your example, I believe you can just use a geodesic polylines that are available in the API. You can set geodesic property of polyline options to true.

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

    LatLng latLng1 = new LatLng(40.7128, 74.0059); // New York
    LatLng latLng2 = new LatLng(51.5074, 0.1278); // London

    Marker marker1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng1).title("Start"));
    Marker marker2 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng2).title("End"));

    List<PatternItem> pattern = Arrays.<PatternItem>asList(new Dash(30), new Gap(20));
    PolylineOptions popt = new PolylineOptions().add(latLng1).add(latLng2)
       .width(10).color(Color.MAGENTA).pattern(pattern)
       .geodesic(true);
    mMap.addPolyline(popt);

    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

    builder.include(marker1.getPosition());
    builder.include(marker2.getPosition());

    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
    int padding = 150; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
    CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
    mMap.moveCamera(cu);
    mMap.animateCamera(cu);
}
```

The resulting polyline is shown in my screenshot

[image]

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, I did the same thing you said, but it's not helping, it's still showing a straight line.

Answer (score 3):

Here is Route object I am using after some improvement from [@xomena](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43665433/3627898)

[Route.java](https://gist.github.com/tamhuynhit/ecb322643455f721c06bca759c0c2ef2)

My changes:

- Use `heading - 90.0` instead of `heading + 90.0`
- Rename variables, make constants (Still figuring out what is some part of the code is doing...)
- Rewrite with my new logic

Basically, I only draw a curve route if the distance between origin and dest is less than 1000km. For longer distance, as I mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46398634/3627898), I found out the part `h1 + i * step` inside the loop make a small error due to `double calculation error` in every iterator and make the final route not being placed correctly.

My safe choice is to draw a crow flight route instead, but my suggestion is not to use k = 1 for this, it's not performance efficiency. I wrote another method which just adds origin and dest points to the Route, skips all other complex calculation.

I will try to come back with this long-curve route problem in the future, for now, this solution still suitable for my problem.

EDIT:

Here is my solution for the second problem so far:

- Change `heading + 90` or `heading - 90` didn't fix the problem, so don't
- Instead, change the `step` variable calculation like this:

  double step = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(distance / 2 / midPerpendicularLength)) * 2 / DEFAULT_CURVE_POINTS;

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, can you share code of an Activity class and things we need to add in our build.gradle as I am getting: cannot resolve symbol 'DirectionApiResponse'... If possible so please upload a demo source code on Github as @xomena did for us... therefore today we are able to make discussions on it and you the second one who is helping in continuing this discussion - Thanks a lot.

Comment: actually I would like to answer this question to earn 100 bounty points :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46103680/map-and-moving-marker-using-google-maps-api (Therefore I am using New York and London as two Geo-Locations) and I want to achieve same thing I achieved already but with Arc shape

Comment: I just used -90 and uploaded screenshot above, please check yet not resolved

Comment: You can ignore the `DirectionApiResponse` part and remove it. Are you sure that you only change -90 and nothing else because it looks weird?

Comment: Yes you can try at your end, I just want to get with these GeoLocations: LatLng latLng1 = new LatLng(40.7128, 74.0059); // New York
        LatLng latLng2 = new LatLng(51.5074, 0.1278); // London    Please share your updated code for the same.... As you know I tried my best...

Comment: Actually, this is a company's project and my Route.java above is all I did for this logic. For us, it's not a critical feature and I am currently busy with other tasks so I will come back to fix this later

Comment: Actually now I want to complete this one ASAP, as I already done 90% of task, so now this is for me craze to done this.... therefore I started bounty

Answer (score 2):

Hy , you need to change your showCurvePolyline method with this method.

```
    private void showCurvedPolyline (LatLng p1, LatLng p2, double k) {
    //Calculate distance and heading between two points
    double d = 0;


if (d == 0)
        d= SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(origin, dest);



double h = SphericalUtil.computeHeading(p1, p2);

    // Calculate midpoint position
    LatLng midPoint = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(p1, d / 2, h);




    //Apply some mathematics to calculate position of the circle center
    double x = (1-k*k)*d*0.5/(2*k);
    double r = (1+k*k)*d*0.5/(2*k);

    LatLng c = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(p, x, h + 90.0);

    //Polyline options
    PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions();
    List<PatternItem> pattern = Arrays.<PatternItem>asList(new Dash(30), new Gap(20));

    //Calculate heading between circle center and two points
    double h1 = SphericalUtil.computeHeading(c, p1);
    double h2 = SphericalUtil.computeHeading(c, p2);

// Calculate position of the curve center point
    double sqrCurvature = DEFAULT_CURVE_ROUTE_CURVATURE * DEFAULT_CURVE_ROUTE_CURVATURE;
    double extraParam = distance / (4 * DEFAULT_CURVE_ROUTE_CURVATURE);
    double midPerpendicularLength = (1 - sqrCurvature) * extraParam;
    double r = (1 + sqrCurvature) * extraParam;

    LatLng midCurvePoint = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(midPoint, midPerpendicularLength, heading - 90.0);

    // Calculate heading between circle center and two points
    double headingToOrigin = SphericalUtil.computeHeading(midCurvePoint, origin);
    double headingToDest = SphericalUtil.computeHeading(midCurvePoint, dest);
    // Calculate positions of points on the curve
    double step = (headingToDest - headingToOrigin) / DEFAULT_CURVE_POINTS;

    List<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < DEFAULT_CURVE_POINTS; ++i) {
        points.add(SphericalUtil.computeOffset(midCurvePoint, r, headingToOrigin + i * step));
    }


    for (int i=0; i <points; i++) {
        LatLng pi = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(c, r, h1 + i * step);
        options.add(pi);
    }

    //Draw polyline
    mMap.addPolyline(options.width(10).color(Color.MAGENTA).geodesic(false).pattern(pattern));
}
```

then you can draw the arcPolyLine.It was provided in the File Provided by previous answer.

Comment: Hy Sonali have a look at this answer.

Comment: There are a few undefined variables like DEFAULT_CURVE_ROUTE_CURVATURE in your code.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to draw an arc. Using the google maps projection API to draw the polylines on an overlay view enables us to do a lot of things. Check this [repo](https://github.com/amalChandran/trail-android) that has an example.

[image]

Comment: How can we do this using Flutter? Someone know please let me know.