# Drawing Curved Polylines Using points, Google Maps JS API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, curve, polyline

There's problem with curved lines calculating. So I have start and end locations, and I'm calculating points between those two positions for drawing Arc using polyline. Everything is Ok, but start and final points of curved line is different then initial.

[picture is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lxAu.png)
[image: picture of problem]

Here method for creating curved points beetween start (path[0]) and end (path[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lxAu.png)) points:

```
getCurvePath(path, iteration) {
    let k = 0.01+(0.05*iteration) //curve radius
    let latLng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(path[0])
    let latLng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(path[1])
    let h = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(
        latLng1,
        latLng2
    )
    let d = 0.0
    let p = null

    //The if..else block is for swapping the heading, offset and distance 
    //to draw curve always in the upward direction
    if (h < 0) {
        d = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(latLng2, latLng1)
        h = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(latLng2, latLng1)
        //Midpoint position
        p = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(latLng2, d * 0.5, h)
    } else {
        d = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(latLng1, latLng2)

        //Midpoint position
        p = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(latLng1, d * 0.5, h)
    }

    //Apply some mathematics to calculate position of the circle center
    let x = (1 - k * k) * d * 0.5 / (2 * k)
    let r = (1 + k * k) * d * 0.5 / (2 * k)

    let c = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(p, x, h + 90)

    //Calculate heading between circle center and two points
    let h1 = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(c, latLng1)
    let h2 = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(c, latLng2)

    //Calculate positions of points on circle border and add them to polyline options
    let numberOfPoints = 500 //more numberOfPoints more smooth curve you will get
    let step = (h2 - h1) / numberOfPoints

    //Create PolygonOptions object to draw on map
    let polygon = []
    polygon.push(latLng1)

    //Create a temporary list of LatLng to store the points that's being drawn on map for curve 
    let temp = []

    //iterate the numberOfPoints and add the LatLng to PolygonOptions to draw curve
    //and save in temp list to add again reversely in PolygonOptions
    for (let i = 0; i<numberOfPoints; i++) {
        let latlng = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(c, r, h1 + i * step)
        polygon.push(latlng) //Adding in PolygonOptions
        temp.push(latlng)    //Storing in temp list to add again in reverse order
    }
    polygon.push(latLng2)
    //iterate the temp list in reverse order and add in PolygonOptions
    for (let i = (temp.length-1); i>=0; i--) {
        polygon.push(temp[i])
    }
    //polygon.push(latLng2)
    return polygon
},
```

Using this method here:

```
const polylines = polylineLocations.map(polyline => {

        return new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: self.getCurvePath([polyline.pathA, polyline.pathB], polyline.iteration),
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: self.getStrokeColor(polyline.value, polyline.meta.PROVIDER),
            // strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 1,
            strokeWeight: self.getStrokeWeight(polyline.capacity),
            meta: polyline.meta,
            value: polyline.value,
            clickable: true
        });

    })
```

finally I can't understand what is the problem? Calculating is not true?

Comment: Related question: [Draw circle's arc on google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956616/draw-circles-arc-on-google-maps)

Comment: Related question: [How to make a dashed curved polyline in Google Maps JS API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34131378/how-to-make-a-dashed-curved-polyline-in-google-maps-js-api)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.  Where did your algorithm come from? Where did your equation for the curve radius (`k`) come from?  What is `r` (and `x`, why are they the same)? Seems like the algorithm might not be accounting for the curvature of the earth, does it work better/differently at the equator?

Comment: Actually I picked this method from this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46411266/draw-arc-polyline-in-google-map.

Comment: And I dont know, what means curve radius k, for me its just iterator for curving. And seems i was wrong.

Comment: This method working true for distance less than 1000 kms, not for my case.

Comment: Which answer did you get that code from?  Or is it from the question?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Please just answer me, how to create array of points for drawing curved polyline beetwen two points. Distance beetwen points more 1000 km.

Comment: I suspect the answer is in one of the duplicates, without a [mcve], I can't reproduce the issue