# Marker is not moving along to path with proper rotation

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have to draw a marker and a path on map; and I want to move the marker to the path, along with rotating it. My marker is moving, but not along the path. Here is my code:

Marker animation method

```
public void animateMarker(final int position, final LatLng startPosition, final LatLng toPosition,
                          final boolean hideMarker) {

    Location source = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    source.setLatitude(sourceLat);
    source.setLongitude(sourceLon);

    Location dest = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    dest.setLatitude(destLat);
    dest.setLongitude(destLon);
    final Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(startPosition)
            .title("My Car")
            .anchor(0.5f,0.5f)
            .snippet("Gurugram")
            .rotation(new Location(source).bearingTo(dest))
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_car)));


    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

    final long duration = 50000;

    final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
            float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed
                    / duration);
            double lng = t * toPosition.longitude + (1 - t)
                    * startPosition.longitude;
            double lat = t * toPosition.latitude + (1 - t)
                    * startPosition.latitude;

            marker.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lng));
            if(preLatLng==null){
                preLatLng=new LatLng(lat,lng);
            }
            else{
                float bearing = (float) bearingBetweenLocations(preLatLng,new LatLng(lat,lng));
                rotateMarker(marker, bearing);
                marker.setZIndex(bearing);
                preLatLng=new LatLng(lat, lng);
            }

            if (t < 1.0) {
                // Post again 16ms later.
                handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
            } else {
                if (hideMarker) {
                    marker.setVisible(false);
                } else {
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Bearing Method

```
private double bearingBetweenLocations(LatLng latLng1,LatLng latLng2) {

    double PI = 3.14159;
    double lat1 = latLng1.latitude * PI / 180;
    double long1 = latLng1.longitude * PI / 180;
    double lat2 = latLng2.latitude * PI / 180;
    double long2 = latLng2.longitude * PI / 180;

    double dLon = (long2 - long1);

    double y = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(lat2);
    double x = Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) - Math.sin(lat1)
            * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(dLon);

    double brng = Math.atan2(y, x);

    brng = Math.toDegrees(brng);
    brng = (brng + 360) % 360;

    return brng;
}
```

Marker Rotation method `rotateMarker` rotates the marker with a rotation value.

```
private boolean isMarkerRotating=false;
private void rotateMarker(final Marker marker, final float toRotation) {
    if(!isMarkerRotating) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        final float startRotation = marker.getRotation();
        final long duration = 2000;

        final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                isMarkerRotating = true;

                long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed / duration);

                float rot = t * toRotation + (1 - t) * startRotation;

                float bearing =  -rot > 180 ? rot / 2 : rot;

                marker.setRotation(bearing);

                if (t < 1.0) {
                    // Post again 16ms later.
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
                } else {
                    isMarkerRotating = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40686476/6950238) answer.