# android animating marker with jsonarray of lat/lons

Tags: android, google-maps

I have this code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length() - 1; i++) {
    JSONObject jb = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String ctime=jb.getString("ctime");
    double lat=Double.parseDouble(jb.getString("lat"));
    double lon=Double.parseDouble(jb.getString("lon"));
    LatLng src = new LatLng(lat,lon);
    jb = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i+1);
    lat=Double.parseDouble(jb.getString("lat"));
    lon=Double.parseDouble(jb.getString("lon"));
    LatLng des = new LatLng(lat,lon);

    Polyline polyline1 = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
        .clickable(true)
        .add(
            new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude),
            new LatLng(des.latitude, des.longitude)));
    polyline1.setTag(ctime);
    polyline1.setEndCap(new RoundCap());  // round start and end                     
    polyline1.setColor(Color.BLUE);  //set color of line
    polyline1.setJointType(JointType.ROUND); 
}
```

It draws a path from json array on google map
I want to add an icon (car) that will animating marker from start to end
And a start stop function
This funy I done it in javascript but I can't find a good example for android :(

Answer (score -1):

i found one that works

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WKfZsCKSXVQ
Sample Java Code : https://gist.github.com/broady/6314689

Comment: Also,  you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40686476/6950238)