# draw polyline in parallel with animation marker in google maps

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-markers, google-polyline

I am using google maps in my application wherein I have to draw the polyline parallel along with the animation marker.Both should move simultaneous.,

Right now, my solution works like this ., First polyline is drawn with new coordinates, then animation marker is moved after.

I have tried few links in the stack overflow.. wherein the solution wasn't there.

This is the solution i'm looking for in swift iOS... the below link is for android.. which works perfectly
[How to move marker along polyline using google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40526350/how-to-move-marker-along-polyline-using-google-map/40686476)

Thanks if you can help me out in these..`

```
@objc func pocDrawPolyline() {
    if poclastShownIndex < (vehicleLocationArray.count) {
        let dict = vehicleLocationArray[poclastShownIndex]
        if let lati = dict["latitude"], let logi = dict["longitude"] {
            let lat = Double(lati as! String)
            let log = Double(logi as! String)
            let location = dict["location"] as? String
            pocCreateVehicleMarkerWith(address: location ?? "School Bus", latitude: lat!, and: log!)
            pocPath.add(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat!, log!))
        }
        polyline.path = pocPath
        polyline.strokeWidth = 3.0
        polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.red
        polyline.map = googleMapView
        poclastShownIndex += 1
    } else {
        //No update from "NOW" API call
    }
}

func pocCreateVehicleMarkerWith(address: String, latitude: Double, and Longitude: Double) {
    // Creates a marker for Vehicle.
    if vechicleMarker.map == nil {
        vechicleMarker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: Longitude)
        vechicleMarker.title = address
        vechicleMarker.icon = UIImage(named: "bus1")
        vechicleMarker.map = googleMapView
    } else {
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.5)
        vechicleMarker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: Longitude)
        vechicleMarker.title = address
        vechicleMarker.icon = UIImage(named: "bus1")
        CATransaction.commit()

        if poclastShownIndex > 0 {
            if let oldLatitude = vehicleLocationArray[poclastShownIndex-1]["latitude"],
                let oldLongitude = vehicleLocationArray[poclastShownIndex-1]["longitude"],
                let newLatitude = vehicleLocationArray[poclastShownIndex]["latitude"],
                let newLongitude = vehicleLocationArray[poclastShownIndex]["longitude"] {

                let oldLat = Double(oldLatitude as! String)
                let oldLon = Double(oldLongitude as! String)
                let newLat = Double(newLatitude as! String)
                let newLon = Double(newLongitude as! String)
                let oldloc = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: oldLat!, longitude: oldLon!)
                let newloc = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: newLat!, longitude: newLon!)

                let distanceInMeters = distance(from: oldloc, to: newloc)
                if distanceInMeters > 0 {
                    print("Rotation Degree ------ \(CLLocationDegrees(getHeadingForDirection(fromCoordinate: oldloc, toCoordinate: newloc)))")
                    vechicleMarker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0.5), y: CGFloat(0.5))
                    vechicleMarker.rotation = CLLocationDegrees(getHeadingForDirection(fromCoordinate: oldloc, toCoordinate: newloc))
                    googleMapView.animate(toLocation: newloc)
                }
            }
        }

    }
}func timerMethod() {
    pocTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10.0, target: self, selector: #selector(pocDrawPolyline), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}`
```

Comment: did you get any solution? this is what I am looking for...

Comment: I have used this method from this below link,.. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/group___geometry_utils.html#gad0c5870bd9d182d22310f84a77888124

Comment: let oldLat = Double(oldLatitude as! String)
let oldLon = Double(oldLongitude as! String)
let newLat = Double(newLatitude as! String)
let newLon = Double(newLongitude as! String)
let oldloc = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: oldLat!, longitude: oldLon!)
let newloc = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: newLat!, longitude: newLon!)let t = GMSGeometryInterpolate(oldloc, newloc, self.count)

Comment: thanks for the reply @Naufal ...can you provide code for the method using which you are able to achieve simultaneous animation. It will be really helpful..

Comment: it works if distance between points is less but not if distance is more & fraction part is also not clear to me...

Comment: // to calculate distance between two lat & long
 func distance(from: CLLocationCoordinate2D, to: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLLocationDistance {let from = CLLocation(latitude: from.latitude, longitude: from.longitude) let to = CLLocation(latitude: to.latitude, longitude: to.longitude)
return from.distance(from: to) }

Comment: func getHeadingForDirection(fromCoordinate fromLoc: CLLocationCoordinate2D, toCoordinate toLoc: CLLocationCoordinate2D) ->Float{
  let fLat: Float = Float((fromLoc.latitude).degreesToRadians)
  let fLng: Float = Float((fromLoc.longitude).degreesToRadians)
  let tLat: Float = Float((toLoc.latitude).degreesToRadians)
  let tLng: Float = Float((toLoc.longitude).degreesToRadians)
  let degree: Float =
   (atan2(sin(tLng - fLng)*cos(tLat),cos(fLat)*sin(tLat)-sin(fLat)*cos(tLat)*cos(tLng-fLng))).radiansToDegrees
  if degree >= 0 {
   return degree
  } else {
   return 360 + degree
  }
 }

Comment: Thanks for the response @Naufal...what are you doing after calculation of distance? I am already using getHeading function..Can u provide me codebase for view controller responsible for animation?

Comment: hi @naufal ....only function I need is how are you setting animation duration based on distance between two points?

Comment: can you provide me sample code for solution?

Comment: I have added the code sample in the above comments,.., just pass the two latitudes and longitudes to the above method.. u could get the result.

Comment: I just need to understand how to use GMSGeometryInterpolate(oldloc, newloc, self.count) in code... I am getting proper heading & directions ...only thing I am not able to achieve is same time animation of marker & path..

Comment: Inorder to draw a path we need this above method which you mentioned.so for that we need two latitudes and two longitudes.first lat,long will be ur source and second lat,long will be destination.you need to pass to that method to draw the line.see this for reference:let oldLat = Double(oldLatitude as! String)
let oldLon = Double(oldLongitude as! String)
let newLat = Double(newLatitude as! String)
let newLon = Double(newLongitude as! String)
let oldloc = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: oldLat!, longitude: oldLon!)
let newloc = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: newLat!, longitude: newLon!)

Comment: thanks for reply..I have one last question I am doing it like  let t = GMSGeometryInterpolate(source, destination, 1.0)
 path.add(t)  
  let rectangle = GMSPolyline(path: path)
  rectangle.strokeWidth = 5.0
    let styles = [GMSStrokeStyle.solidColor(.clear),
                     GMSStrokeStyle.solidColor(.black)]
       let lengths: [NSNumber] = [10, 10]
       rectangle.spans = GMSStyleSpans(rectangle.path!, styles, lengths,GMSLengthKind.rhumb)...still the path is being drawn before marker..how do I handle animation duration?

Comment: assign static var updateDuration = 0.0
 static var movingDuration = 0.0 let animation DurationGap = 1.0/Constants.movingDuration _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true){ tim in
       self.count += self.animationDurationGap
       self.count = self.count.roundToDecimal(2)
       print(self.count)
       if self.count > 1.0 {
        self.createVehicleMarker(address: "", latitude: newLat!, and: newLon!)
        self.pocPath.add(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(newLat!, newLon!))
        self.createPolyLineWithPath(path: self.pocPath).. just add timer to the above method