# Flutter- How to move marker along polyline using google map

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-markers, flutter-animation, fluttermap

I am trying to move the marker according to the polyline with animation.
I found this in java but I wasn't able to convert it to dart ([moving marker along polyline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40526350/how-to-move-marker-along-polyline-using-google-map/40686476))

[image: map marker]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after searching, this package solved my problem [line_animator](https://github.com/ibrierley/line_animator) I used it with the [flutter_map](https://github.com/fleaflet/flutter_map) package and its works fine